# Parsing JSON with Jettison

Tags: java, json, jettison

I want to use Jettison for parsing JSON responses for making them consistent in an XML format.
So far, I couldn't get any further in the parsing part.

I tried to apply [this example](http://jettison.codehaus.org/User%27s+Guide#User%27sGuide-Parsing)

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject({"Type":2,"Value":{"rsp":true,"id":"5B721163"}});
AbstractXMLStreamReader reader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj);

String s = reader.getName().getLocalPart();
String t = reader.getText();

reader.next();
String u = reader.getName().getLocalPart();
System.out.print(s+t+u);
```

So I'm wondering why the output is "Type2Type" and not "Type2Value" and how I get to the second one?

Answer (score 1):

as in XML, Jettison assume your json has a root element and `.next()` events types include: `START_ELEMENT,END_ELEMENT,COMMENT...`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(
        "{\"root\": {\"Type\":2,\"Value\":{\"rsp\":true,\"id\":\"5B721163\"}}}");
for (AbstractXMLStreamReader reader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj); reader
        .hasNext(); reader.next()) {
    String s = reader.getLocalName();
    String t = reader.getText();
    int evenType = reader.getEventType();
    System.out.println(String.format(
                "Name: %s, text: %s, event type: %d", s, t, evenType));
}
```

give me:

```
Name: root, text: null, event type: 7 (START_DOCUMENT)
Name: root, text: null, event type: 1 (START_ELEMENT)
Name: Type, text: 2, event type: 1
Name: Type, text: 2, event type: 4 (CHARACTERS)
Name: Type, text: null, event type: 2 (END_ELEMENT)
Name: Value, text: null, event type: 1
Name: rsp, text: true, event type: 1
Name: rsp, text: true, event type: 4
Name: rsp, text: null, event type: 2
Name: id, text: 5B721163, event type: 1
Name: id, text: 5B721163, event type: 4
Name: id, text: null, event type: 2
Name: Value, text: null, event type: 2
Name: root, text: null, event type: 2
```

Comment: for the same reason it will only parse root1 in the following xml <root1/><root2/>

Comment: StAXON has a virtual root configuration option, see http://java.dzone.com/articles/staxon-json-stax `As XML requires a single root element, but JSON documents often don’t have one, this is an important feature required to read and write existing JSON formats` I didnt find the equivalent in Jettison project